# Structures in Categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

This is a follow up to my previous question here:

[Meaning of "espece de structure avec morphismes" in EGA Chapter 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026130/meaning-of-espece-de-structure-avec-morphismes-in-ega-chapter-0)

My reference is this arxiv note https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.08737v3.pdf.

Let $\mathcal X$ be a category.  A *concrete category over $\mathcal X$* is a category $\mathcal C$, together with a faithful functor $| \cdot |: \mathcal C \rightarrow \mathcal X$.  A *structure* in such a concrete category is an equivalence class of objects of $\mathcal C$, where we say that $A \sim A'$ if $|A| = |A'|$ and if there is an isomorphism $f: A \rightarrow A'$ in $\mathcal C$.

In general, if $A \sim A'$, there is no reason that $A$ should equal $A'$.  However, the note claims on the first page that this is true for $\mathcal C = \textrm{Top}$ and $\mathcal X = \textrm{Set}$.  I do not see why this should be the case.

So the claim is that if $X$ is a set endowed with two topologies $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$, and if there exists a bijection $\phi: X \rightarrow X$ which is a homeomorphism $(X,\mathcal T_1) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal T_2)$, then the identity map is also a homeomorphism $(X,\mathcal T_1) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal T_2)$.

But I believe this is false.  For example, let $X$ be a set with two elements $a, b$, and let

$$\mathcal T_1 = \{ \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{a\}\}$$

$$\mathcal T_2 = \{ \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{b\}\}$$

Then the bijection $X \rightarrow X$ which switches $a$ and $b$ is a homeomorphism $(X,\mathcal T_1) \rightarrow (X,\mathcal T_2)$.  But this identity map is not a homeomorphism.  Am I misunderstanding the claim in the note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counter-example seems correct; the paper reads ambigiously in its definition of the equivalence relation: a better explicit choice (which makes the above work) is that $A\sim A'$ if there is an isomorphism $A\xrightarrow{f}A'$ with $|A|\xrightarrow{|f|}|A'|$ being the identity morphism of $|A|=|A'|$, rather than merely an endo(hence auto)morphism.

Looking at the paper as a whole, it's really just talking about (concrete) **topological categories**, which you can easily read about in the referenced freely available [Abstract and Concrete Categories](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/) (perhaps you can also look at Oswald Wyler's *Lecture Notes in Topoi and Quasi-topoi* which begins with a concise "Categorical toolchest" including a very brief section on topological categories).